# ld: 35 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, cocoapods

I just started using cocoapods and can't figure out what the heck is going on. I've installed a library for a ViewController and keep getting the following errors:

```
Ld /Users/dominikandrzejczuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMSlideMenu-eqdwyqtxcitqwzavvophqeeuqgyn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMSlideMenu.app/AMSlideMenu normal i386
cd "/Users/dominikandrzejczuk/AMSlideMenu/AMSlideMenuDemo-with Storyboard"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/dominikandrzejczuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMSlideMenu-eqdwyqtxcitqwzavvophqeeuqgyn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dominikandrzejczuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMSlideMenu-eqdwyqtxcitqwzavvophqeeuqgyn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/dominikandrzejczuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMSlideMenu-eqdwyqtxcitqwzavvophqeeuqgyn/Build/Intermediates/AMSlideMenu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMSlideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/AMSlideMenu.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods-AMSlideMenu -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dominikandrzejczuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMSlideMenu-eqdwyqtxcitqwzavvophqeeuqgyn/Build/Intermediates/AMSlideMenu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMSlideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/AMSlideMenu_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dominikandrzejczuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMSlideMenu-eqdwyqtxcitqwzavvophqeeuqgyn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMSlideMenu.app/AMSlideMenu

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AMSlideMenuContentSegue in:
/Users/dominikandrzejczuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMSlideMenu-eqdwyqtxcitqwzavvophqeeuqgyn/Build/Intermediates/AMSlideMenu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMSlideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/AMSlideMenuContentSegue.o
/Users/dominikandrzejczuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMSlideMenu-eqdwyqtxcitqwzavvophqeeuqgyn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-AMSlideMenu.a(AMSlideMenuContentSegue.o)

ld: 35 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
wclang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried removing the Library path in build settings, I've tried reinstalling a pod install and pretty much every other option recommended on the web.

I have no idea where to go from here...

Comment: You are linking in the `AMSlideMenu.a` library and building it as a target, by the look of it.  Only you can untangle that mess.